# Don't reset vim tab to the beinning line

Tags: indentation, buffers

I have a question about tabs within vim and I'm using VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jan 17 2018 20:33:56) Included patches: 1-1255 Compiled by _pbuild@amd64.ports.openbsd.org

tab bindings:

```
" This replaces :tabnew which I used to bind to this mapping
nmap <leader>t :enew<cr>
"
" Move to the next buffer
nmap <leader>l :bnext<CR>
"
" Move to the previous buffer
nmap <leader>h :bprevious<CR>
"
" Close the current buffer and move to the previous one
" This replicates the idea of closing a tab
nmap <leader>bq :bp <BAR> bd #<CR>
"
" Show all open buffers and their status
nmap <leader>bl :ls<CR>
```

The question I have is, is it possible to prevent the cursor from jumping to the beginning of the line? If I have two different files open and I'm half way on the line, when I switch to " file2" and back to "file", I'll be on the correct line, but at the beginning of the line. This causes me to use either w or w# to get back to where I was.

I don't seem to have this issue if I were to vs "file" and "file2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unset the `'startofline'` option:

```
:set nostartofline
```

See `:help 'startofline'`

Comment: Awesome, it looks like this is set by default.